# Deleting an Orphaned user in AD affects the sync or deletes the user from AAD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory

I have an Orphaned AD user (Deleted the DC in 2018), however the user is active in AAD, I need to move this user to another DC, If I remove the user from the OnPrem AD, will it remove it from AAD? AAD last sync was in 2018, however the user is active and has been logging on regularly.

Another question, can I create a new user in the OnPrem AD, and then link the AAD with this new user?

User impact must be 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one test user **"Sarita"** in my on-prem AD and ran the AD Sync Cycle using command like below:

```
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle –PolicyType Delta
```

**Response:**

[image]

After running the above command, **Sarita** is synced to Azure Active Directory successfully as below:

[image]

Now I deleted the **Sarita** from my On-premises AD and ran the Sync Cycle again as below:

[image]

After the Sync cycle, **Sarita** from Azure Active Directory got deleted automatically like below:

[image]

I tried to login with the **same account** now and it shows error like below:

[image]

> Can I create a new user in the OnPrem AD, and then link the AAD with this new user?

No, we cannot create new user in the OnPrem AD and link to Azure Active Directory with this new user.

Please **note** that, whenever new user is created in the OnPrem AD, an **SID** value is created for that user.

If you create new user now, **SID** values will be different, and we cannot link it to AAD as it will be created with different attributes.